# Data in a onTap event flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i have a `List<Row>` created in a `forEach` loop inside a async method, this list is assignated in a `DataTable`, inside each row created i have a `GestureDetector`, the trouble is:

When i try to put data inside of the `onTap()` event of the `GestureDetector` the data is data from the last iteration if the loop.

here is the async method:

```
Future<List<DataRow>> rowEquipos(BuildContext context) async{
    DBInteractions database = DBInteractions();

    Map<String, String> equiposData = await database.listadoEquiposActivos();
    List<DataRow> rows = [];
    List<String> tempEquiposData = [];
    int contador = 0;

    //comienza foreach de datos de equipos
    equiposData.forEach((key, value) {
      contador++;
      tempEquiposData.add(value);
      if(contador % 6 == 0){
        rows.add(
            DataRow(
                cells: [
                  DataCell(
                    GestureDetector(
                        child: Text(tempEquiposData[1]),
                        onTap: (){
                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context)
                                => DetallesEquipo(datosEquipo: tempEquiposData[2])
                          ));
                          //TODO: habilitar vista de detalles del equipo, además de ajustes (habilitar/deshabilitar)
                        },
                        onLongPressEnd: (LongPressEndDetails details){
                            null;
                        },
                    )
                  ),
                  DataCell(
                      GestureDetector(
                        child: Text(tempEquiposData[2]),
                        onTap: (){
                          print(tempEquiposData);
                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context)
                              => DetallesEquipo(datosEquipo: tempEquiposData[2])
                          ));
                        },
                        onLongPressEnd: (LongPressEndDetails details){
                          null;
                        },
                      )
                  ),
                ],
            )
        );
        
        contador = 0;
        tempEquiposData = [];
      }
    });

    return rows;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deeply searched through the flutter docs and found another way to make dinamic rows with the `List<T>.generate()` method and it worked fine.

```
List<DataRow>.generate(listaEquipos.length, (index) => DataRow(
                    cells:[
                      DataCell(
                          GestureDetector(
                            child: Text(listaEquipos[index][1]),
                            onTap: (){
                              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (BuildContext context)
                                  => DetallesEquipo(datosEquipo: listaEquipos[index][2])
                              ));
                              //TODO: habilitar vista de detalles del equipo, además de ajustes (habilitar/deshabilitar)
                            },
                            onLongPressEnd: (LongPressEndDetails details){
                              null;
                            },
                          )
                      ),
                      DataCell(
                          GestureDetector(
                            child: Text(listaEquipos[index][2]),
                            onTap: (){
                              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (BuildContext context)
                                  => DetallesEquipo(datosEquipo: listaEquipos[index][2])
                              ));
                            },
                            onLongPressEnd: (LongPressEndDetails details){
                              null;
                            },
                          )
                      ),
                    ]
                  ))
```